# How to detect modification of JS function?

Tags: javascript, console

I have a function that performs a SHA256 hash algorithm. It is client side, which means that it can easily be modified in the console like so:

```
function sha256(){ //Your modifications }
```

The ability for the client to modify the function via the console exposes a security loophole. Is there a way to detect the modification of a JavaScript function (if possible)? E.g, check whether the function itself has been modified.

The security loophole in question is the ability to be able to modify the sha256 to return a result that isn't actually hashed.

**Example Modification**

Let's say the sha256 function is originally:

```
function sha256(){
   console.log("nope");
}
```

But the client changes it in the console by entering the following:

```
function sha256(){
    console.log("sure");
}
```

Comment: I believe you should do those sort of things on the backend. I mean, even you'd find a way to check if a function has been modified, the user can easily modify the "checking" function.

Comment: I could think of many ways to detect if a function has been changed, but before going there, why is your function accessible from the global scope? That is the first security flaw.

Comment: I would never consider doing hashing at the front-end. Even if you *can* detect malicious changes to the hash-function. any visitor can easily reverse engineer your algorithm and keys and use that for a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I agree with you, I would absolutely do any security critical operation server side, but I think there are some ways to make it really, really difficult for someone to vulnerate your client side function.

Comment: You are all completely right. The back story is not important however. It just came up in my head, and I decided to include it. If I was to do authentication, I would most definitely do it back end.

Comment: @BartBarnard agree with your too, but you are assuming that hashing is for passwords management. Maybe the function is intended for another use.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Amm, you can minify / uglify the js code so it would be less convenient. But if a certain user has an intention - I don't think that it would stop them.

Comment: @OfirBaruch browsers are capable of doing script integrity check to avoid that. And once the code is loaded in memory, well, there comes the difficult, but interesting part.

Comment: And what ever code you use to check if it is modified can be modified. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Please read the question comments and @Bergi answer for very important security considerations. See this answer as a theoretical exercise. Do not use this for security critical scenarios.***

Assuming that `myFunction` is already in the current scope:

```js
function myFunction() {};

const check = (() => {
    const str = myFunction.toString();
    return (fn) => fn.toString() === str; 
})();

check(myFunction); // true
check(function myFunction() {}); // true

// ANYTHING ELSE WILL BE false
```

Comment: "Made by human, broken by human..."  Good suggestion, but here's one way to defeat this proposed scheme.  Simply usurp the toString prototype.  Ie, `const fx = myFunction.toString(); Function.prototype.toString = (() => fx)` and then redefine `myFunction()` to anything, and the `fn.toString()` call inside `check()` will always return  the original definition of `myFunction()`...

Comment: @Trentium yes, I know there are many ways to defeat this strategy, that is why I wrote the security warning. But it is the basic idea though. At least the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

> The ability for the client to modify the function via the console exposes a security loophole.

No, it's not. The user is free to do on their computer whatever they choose to do, with or without the code provided by you.

It would be a security loophole if a user could affect the code running on *other* user's computers, but that's not possible through the console.

If modifying the clientside code poses a threat *to your server* or other users, then there's a security loophole in your server software. This threat exists whether the user modifies code using the console or not.

Comment: I realize @Bergi that what I'm about to say isn't directly applicable to the question at hand, but in my mind is related, maybe warranting another question... In a situation where one has developed a website and includes a number of third party scripts, it seems that there's the possibility that a third party script can introduce code that sweeps the global space (window vars, DOM, etc) all within the client's browser session for sensitive information (names, credentials, etc) and expatriates the data to another server.

Comment: In such a situation it seems that there needs to be the type of segragation sought by the OP.  Am interested in your take on this observation, particularly whether newer versions of ECMAScript have incorporated features (eg, imports?) that allow orchestration of code within the client to enforce segregation...

Comment: @Trentium Yes, that case is unrelated to the OP where console modifications would only affect the hacker themselves. Regarding third party scripts, that's exactly the reason why you should not use them - they can attack your users, possibly without you even knowing. And no, there are no ECMAScript features being introduced to avoid this. The solution offered by browsers is [subresource integretity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) to specify a version of the script you can vet yourself, or restricting the script to a sandboxed iframe.